# Why there is there an error when using React strict mode?

Tags: reactjs

React newbie here

I got this error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'StrictMode' of undefined

I think this is because re 'React.StrictMode' React is not defined. When commenting out the two lines mentioning React.StrictMode the code works fine. Doing some experimenting, I found that the issue is with the import.

`import {React, useState} from 'react';` does not import `React` causing it to be undefined and error with this part of the code:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Doing this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {useState} from 'react';
```

is fine.

I'm wondering why the first method doesn't work

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `React` is default export so you annot import it like `import {React, useState} from 'react'`  import like this `import React,{ useState} from 'react'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React is a default export ( export statement looks like this - `export default react`). If it is default export then it should be imported like this `import React from 'react'`

useState is not default export ( export statement will be like - `export useState;`). If it is not default export then it should be imported like this `import {useState} from 'react';`

For more detailed explanation this blog will help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import